# ¿Cómo importar el nombre de todos los íconos de FAS5?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify, font-awesome, icons

Estoy tratando de hacer un select con Vue y Vuetify para que el usuario pueda escoger algún ícono de [@fortawesome/fortawesome-free](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free) que le guste para agregarlo a su perfil. Quiero para ello hacer [algo parecido a este ejemplo](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/#usage) de vuetify donde escoja el ícono desde un select, sin embargo, me faltan los valores de los íconos, que son los que quiero importar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello estuve buscando y encontré [este archivo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js) donde se tiene una variable JSON con todos los nombres de los íconos, sin embargo no he podido importarla. Y no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo puesto que está en una función auto ejecutable

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :items="icons"
    label="Items"
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
import * as icons from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min';

export default {
  data() {
   return {
    icons: []
   }
  }
  beforeMount() {
    console.log(icons)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Obtener la lista no es tan complicado; desde el mismo html de la página de FA, ya sea con xpath o expresiones regulares. Sin embargo, habría que preguntarse si a los usuarios les gustará navegar por una lista de mas de 1600 iconos, sin contar que todas las familias son mas de 7800.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a hacer scrapping de su [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet)?

Comment: No necesariamente scrapping, por que sería sólo una vez; puedes prescindir del lenguaje de programación y hacerlo con un procesador/editor de textos.